# Aggregate json arrays from multiple files using jq, grouping by key

Tags: json, jq

I would like to aggregate two or more files into a single json, and aggregate arrays under a same key.

file1.json

```
{
  "shapes": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "circle"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "square"
    }
  ]
}
```

file2.json

```
{
  "shapes": [
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "triangle"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected result :

```
{
  "shapes": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "circle"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "square"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "triangle"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can do this with the following jq command :

```
jq -s '{shapes: map(.shapes)|add }' file*.json
```

But this requires me to know the **shapes** attribute and hardcode it. Is there a simple way I can get the same result without ever using the key name explicitly?

Comment: What if the top-level object in one or more of the files has more than one key?

Comment: I'm handling a api response which has only one key. So it does not affect this case, but for the general case, all keys not named **shapes** would effectively be discarded, which might be what I want, or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that’s suitable when each top-level object has only one key, and that is both efficient and conceptually simple.  It assumes jq is invoked with the -n option.

```
reduce inputs as $in (null;
   ($in|keys_unsorted[0]) as $k | { ($k): (.[$k] + $in[$k]) })
```

or slightly more compactly:

```
reduce inputs as $in (null; ($in|keys_unsorted[0]) as $k | .[$k] += $in[$k] )
```

Comment: I'm changing my accepted answer to this one, as it's the one I'll use.

```jq -n 'reduce inputs as $in (null; ($in|keys[0]) as $k | .[$k] += $in[$k] )' file*.json```
@peak : is the **unsorted** part only for performance? In my specific case, I don't really care, except sorted keys are a slight bonus in readability.

Comment: If the top-level objects have only one key, as this answer assumes, then of course functionally it makes no difference; computationally, the difference is probably very small or maybe even non-existent.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that also solves a more general problem: first, it handles arbitrarily many input files; and second, it forms the "sum" by key, for every key, on the assumption that every top-level key is array-valued.

The generic function:

```
  # the values at each key are assumed to be arrays
  def aggregate(stream): 
    reduce stream as $o ({}; 
      reduce ($o|keys_unsorted[]) as $k (.; 
        .[$k] += $o[$k] ));
```

To avoid "slurping", we will use `inputs`:

```
aggregate(inputs)
```

The invocation must therefore use the -n command-line option:

```
jq -n -f program.jq *.json
```

Comment: Hi @peak , I haven't been able to reproduce the solution. I saved the function as program.jq and ran  `jq -n -f program.jq *.json` but I got **null** as a response. I suppose I have to do something w/ the aggregate statement.

Comment: @moogly81 try after appending line `aggregate(inputs)` in the file `program.jq`

Comment: ah, ok, this works ! aggregate(inputs) is menat to be at the end of the program.jq file

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. This can handle any number of files. All inputs are assumed to be json objects with all values inside as arrays. All such arrays are aggregated after grouping by keys. It outputs an object which has keys associated with corresponding aggregated arrays.

```
jq -s 'map(to_entries)|add|group_by(.key)|
    map( { "key": (.[0].key), "value": (map(.value)|add)})|
    from_entries' file1.json file2.json
```

For your sample input this gives:

```
{
  "shapes": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "circle"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "square"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "triangle"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I don't consider it **a simple way**, like stated in the question, but I guess it's just not that easy to do.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is very inefficient (both in terms of memory usage and speed), and also problematic (e.g. because of the way it uses `flatten`).